# Do you think 3200 MHz 16 GB master RAM plus 3200 MHz 4 GB slave RAM (20GB total) will cause any bottleneck?

Tags: memory, performance, gaming, ramdisk

Some genius product developers decided to put 8 GB of ram to  RTX 3060 laptop. I know that Ryzen 5 5600h CPU of this laptop is good enough to not create any bottleneck for RTX 3060 but I am trying to increase my RAM. It currently has 4GB+4GB RAM; want to remove 1 of them and put 16GB same frequency ram. How will this affect the performance? Would 8 GB + 8 GB have better performance than this?

Summary of the questions is: 4GB RAM will prevent 16GB RAM to work efficiently? Maybe 16GB alone would have better performance or maybe 8 plus 8 ram might be better than this combination of 16 plus 4. Any ideas would help

Comment: *"genius product developers"* - I bet they sold it in more than the base config you decided to buy. Can't blame 'em for putting a cheap one at the bottom of the stack.

Comment: @Tetsujin I cant configure it as 16 GB ram, they sell it as it is on my region. Of course there are 16GB models but more expensive. So 2 4 GB rams are useless now if I upgrade it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Laptop] currently has 4GB+4GB RAM; want to remove 1 of them and put 16GB same frequency ram. How will this affect the performance?

It will run slower because it won't be able to use dual channel. You'll have more RAM in total though. It's a tradeoff.

> Would 8 GB + 8 GB have better performance than this?

Yes, but less RAM in total.

> Maybe 16GB alone would have better performance?

No, it will be comparable to 4+16 GB in terms of RAM speed but with less capacity.

Comment: I am surprised that we can not use dual channel even with same frequencies because of size difference

Comment: @MuhammetnurAmangeldiyev That's how it is and always has been.

Comment: Actually Intel chips support dual channel with different size modules. I can't remember what it's called and can't find any sources unfortunately.